# How to effectively copy, paste and display an entire Wordpress folder?

Tags: wordpress, directory

I always make make backups in the following way: project0.1, project0.2, and so on. I just started using Wordpress today and it seems like modyfing the root folder's name makes some elements display: `Not Found` (the CSS still the same).

This happens when I copy and paste the root folder of my Wordpress and assign it another name.

Which are the files where I have to modify the root folder's name or the problems is in the database?

Comment: I don't understand. What exactly is the problem / the question? What are you doing with the copied folders? One thing you can't do is copy something to another folder and expect the new folder to work straight away: There will be references pointing to the old folder in both the file system and the database.

Comment: @Pekka in case I want to modify my whole Wordpress site offline (e.g. using WAMP's localhost). Making a copy of the live site and making it work offline in my localhost.

Answer (score 1):

The wordpress config file `wp-config.php` will usually contain <strike>the web root and</strike> the database settings.

In the database, there is an `options` table that will contain 1-2 settings containing the base URL; also, there may be links pointing to the live site in the posts.

Comment: I wish to move a site that I have been working on on my localhost to production for the first time(ie: I'm not interested in any posts, users or other dynamic content since they were all dummy content). Should it suffice to simply copy the relevant folders to the production server, change the wp-config to the new database location, and copy the database to the production database server (clearing all tables except for `wp_content` - since the rest hold dynamic content)? Or can there be things that might break?

Comment: @theyuv that sounds sufficient, but it's been a while since I've worked with a WP install! If in doubt, check out the official guide https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: Thank you...I meant `wp_options` table, not `wp_content`